# NameNotFoundException for ActiveMQ

Tags: wildfly, message-queue, activemq-artemis

I created a standalone program which sends messages to a queue residing in JBoss EAP 7.0. I configured my queue details in `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<jms-queue name = "QUEUE.ONE" entries = "java:/jms/QUEUE.ONE"/>
```

My program is getting connected to the JBoss server. It gets the JNDI lookup value from this code:

```java
String destination = System.getProperty("destination", "jms/queue/QUEUE.ONE");
```

However, when performing the lookup it is showing:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException "queue name"
```

Comment: Please show the code where you access the queue and the section of the standalone.xml where you configured the queue

Comment: Is it JBoss EAP 7 or JBoss AS 7 ?

Comment: @ehsavoie it's Jboss EAP 7

Comment: <jms-queue name = "QUEUE.ONE" entries = "java:/jms/QUEUE.ONE"/>  ----> standalone.xml.                      String destination = System.getProperty("destination","jms/queue/QUEUE.ONE") --> class

Comment: How do you access the queue in your code ? Is it being injected ?

Comment: Also is it EAP 7.0, 7.1, or 7.2 ?

Comment: Your program is running in the server or is it  client ?

Comment: It is EAP 7.0 , my code is running on the client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208571/discussion-between-padma-kotish-and-ehsavoie).

Comment: It would really help to know *exactly* what `String` value you're using for your lookup.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who may have this same question in the future. If not, please clarify what wasn't addressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the proper `entries` for your JMS queue in order to expose it to remote clients. You need to have an entry using the `java:jboss/exported` namespace, e.g.:

```xml
<jms-queue name="QUEUE.ONE" entries="java:/jms/QUEUE.ONE java:jboss/exported/jms/QUEUE.ONE"/>
```

The on your client you'd use this lookup: `jms/QUEUE.ONE`.